# Angular patchValue not setting input field value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, formbuilder

I am trying to set an input value via form group using `patchValue()` but the input still remains blank, this is my code sample...

> component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="createStoreForm" (ngSubmit)="createStore()" novalidate>
  <label for="user">Unique User ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="storeProfile.user" [formControl]="createStoreForm.controls['user']" readonly>
    <div *ngIf="createStoreForm.controls['user'].hasError('required') && formSubmitAttempt" class="form-error">Store user is required</div>
</form>
```

> component.ts

```
export class storeProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  storeProfile: any = {};
  userData: any = {};
  userId: any;
  createStoreForm: FormGroup;
  formSubmitAttempt: boolean;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private storeSrv: StoreService, private router: Router) {
    this.createStoreForm = fb.group({
      'user': ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let tempUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if (tempUser) {
      this.userData = JSON.parse(tempUser);
      this.userId = this.userData.id;
    };

  this.createStoreForm.patchValue({
    'user': this.userId.id,  // this.userId.id = undefined here
  });
 }
}
```

What is the right way to pass value from `localStorage` to the `input field` on the form?

Comment: first you set `this.userId = this.userData.id` and then again you set the form with `this.userId.id`. which is effectiely `this.userData.id.id`. are you sure thats correct?

Comment: thanks for noticing, you are right but changing that didn't fix the issue tho. @deezg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove ngModel and use createStoreForm.value to get from values

```
<form [formGroup]="createStoreForm" (ngSubmit)="createStore()" novalidate>
  <label for="user">Unique User ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" [formControl]="createStoreForm.controls['user']" readonly>
    <div *ngIf="createStoreForm.controls['user'].hasError('required') && formSubmitAttempt" class="form-error">Store user is required</div>
</form>

export class storeProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  storeProfile: any = {};
  userData: any = {};
  userId: any;
  createStoreForm: FormGroup;
  formSubmitAttempt: boolean;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private storeSrv: StoreService, private router: Router) {
    this.createStoreForm = fb.group({
      'user': ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let tempUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if (tempUser) {
      this.userData = JSON.parse(tempUser);
      this.userId = this.userData.id;
    };

  this.createStoreForm.patchValue({
    'user': this.userId.id,  
  });
 }

 public createStore(){
  console.log(this.createStoreForm.value); // get from values 
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution retreived the userId to the view but onsubmit it is ommited and not submitted with the form @Muhammad

Comment: @CE0 I just update my answer about how you can get the from value on submit

Comment: Now it works, thanks man. passing `this.createStoreForm.value` worked right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set value after getting value from local storage like this,

Try this -

```
export class storeProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  storeProfile: any = {};
  userData: any = {};
  userId: any;
  createStoreForm: FormGroup;
  formSubmitAttempt: boolean;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private storeSrv: StoreService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let tempUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if (tempUser) {
      this.userData = JSON.parse(tempUser);
      this.userId = this.userData.id;
    };

    this.createStoreForm = this.fb.group({
      'user': [this.userId.id, Validators.required],
    });
 }
}

<form [formGroup]="createStoreForm" (ngSubmit)="createStore()" novalidate>
  <label for="user">Unique User ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" formControl="user" readonly>
    <div *ngIf="createStoreForm.controls['user'].hasError('required') && formSubmitAttempt" class="form-error">Store user is required</div>
</form>
```

Comment: error thrown here
`this.createStoreForm = fb.group({'user': [this.userId.id, Validators.required]})`

`cannot find name fb`

Comment: opps !! just forgot to add `this`, try my updated answer.

Comment: yeah i tried that already and error was `Property 'fb' does not exist on type 'StoreProfileComponent'` :(